# How can I keep apps "always on top" in Lion?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, applications, software

With past versions of OSX, I used Afloat, but ever since I moved to Lion, it stopped working for programs like Evernote & Chrome.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a program that will let me keep any other program's window 'always on top'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a boring answer, but it looks like Afloat has been updated to support Lion:

http://infinite-labs.net/kb/afloat/af-lion.html

Comment: Thanks, but many programs that were updated for Lion don't work with Afloat any more. That's why I came here to ask this question.

Comment: Have you tried the last release? According to the release page for Afloat 2.4, it should now work with App Store sandboxed apps.

Comment: No longer under active development :( Anyone found another solution?

Answer (score -1):

I use for it expanding to whole desktop without thinking about this. 
Does your software support for lion full screen?

**PS:** I've found perfect article at OS X daily: http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/22/enable-full-screen-support-all-apps-os-x-lion-maximizer/
This software allows full screen for any software that doesn't support full screen mode natively

PPS: Chrome and Evernote have support lion's full screen mode natively.

Comment: Thanks, but the goal isn't to do a full-screen. It's to keep one window on top of another. So, if I'm typing in Chrome, I'd like to have evernote's note window on top of it so I can see it.