# Keep app "always on top" in El Capitan

Tags: macos, applications, iterm

Is there a way to keep in app always in front of other apps?

The tool referenced [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28593/how-can-i-keep-apps-always-on-top-in-lion) - [Afloat](https://github.com/millenomi/afloat) - doesn't work in El Capitan. Would love to keep iTerm2 always in the forefront but can't find a way to do this.

Comment: Consider changing El Capitan to macOS so the question has a broader spectrum

Comment: macOS only references Sierra and forward, not El Capitan and back  If you look on Apple's sites it uses OS X for El Cap and previous.  For this question, the title should remain with 'El Capitan' because that's what the OP is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to achieve this functionality with an application like "Afloat" as you mentioned already. But it seems to only work in El Capitan if you permanently turn off System Integrity Protection (SIP) which isn't recommended.

However, here is the link to the program: https://github.com/millenomi/afloat

How to turn off SIP: https://github.com/millenomi/afloat/issues/22